# python unittest assertRaises

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, testing, python-unittest

I copied this verbatim from python.org unittest documentation:

```
import random
import unittest

class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.seq = range(10)

    def test_shuffle(self):
        # make sure the shuffled sequence does not lose any elements
        random.shuffle(self.seq)
        self.seq.sort()
        self.assertEqual(self.seq, range(10))

        # should raise an exception for an immutable sequence
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, random.shuffle, (1,2,3))

    def test_choice(self):
        element = random.choice(self.seq)
        self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

    def test_sample(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            random.sample(self.seq, 20)
        for element in random.sample(self.seq, 5):
            self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But I get this error message from python 2.7.2 [GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)] on linux2:

```
.E.
======================================================================
ERROR: test_sample (__main__.TestSequenceFunctions)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 23, in test_sample
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
TypeError: failUnlessRaises() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

How can I get `assertRaises()` to work properly?

Comment: The above code works fine on Arch - Python 2.7.5. Upgrade your python?

Answer (score 7):

The ability to use unittest.TestCase.AssertRaises() as context manager was added in python 2.7.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises

Answer (score 5):

Check that you are really using 2.7 python.

Tested using `pythonbrew`:

```
$ pythonbrew use 2.7.2
$ python test.py 
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

OK
$ pythonbrew use 2.6.5
$ python test.py
.E.
======================================================================
ERROR: test_sample (__main__.TestSequenceFunctions)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 23, in test_sample
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
TypeError: failUnlessRaises() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: "Changed in version 2.7: Added the ability to use assertRaises() as a context manager." According to [python manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 2.7 and still seeing this issue, it could be because you're not using python's `unittest` module. Some other modules like `twisted` provide `assertRaises` and though they try to maintain compatibility with python's `unittest`, your particular version of that module may be out of date.